# Spawning button instances within a view from a Zend form, each with it's own unique id

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm a big fan of Zend's form feature where you can master element format in one place and instantiate elements at will to maintain a consistent look and feel within my webapp.

I have a need to create several copies of a button within a form in order to allow button driven actions against a table record.

I can easily write PHP code to write a unique button for each record each button with it's own unique onclick event to pass a parameter (the record number) to a modal or redirect.  But I'm curious to know whether I can spawn several instances of a standard form element each with it's own seperate onclick action.

I can easily set the onclick element for any button I want to within the view but it would be great if I could do something like this:

foreach loop

echo $this->form->bttndelete_.$recordnumber;

Each with it's own onclick=showmodaldelete($recordnumber).

Is something like this possible or is it merely wishful thinking.

As mentioned, I know how to achieve this via raw PHP however I'm keen to know if there's a more elegant way to achieve my goal.  Or am I dreaming?!  :)

Many thanks,
Chris